# Google Sheets Vlookup with dynamic result i.e. keep blank rows and show result in next matching value

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

Column A in the below image is user input and result is expected in column B and C. Result is to be derived from the data available in Column F and G by matching column A with Column E.

[image]
Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you do not have data column (B) in input table then how you will know for 3rd `1` that result will be blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in B3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A&"×"&COUNTIFS(A3:A, A3:A, ROW(A3:A), "<="&ROW(A3:A)), 
 {E3:E&"×"&COUNTIFS(E3:E, E3:E, ROW(E3:E), "<="&ROW(E3:E)), F3:G}, {2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Player0 thanks for your excellent solution, really brilliant, you always think out of box. Hats off to you....

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula then drag down and across.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($F$3:$G$8,$E$3:$E$8=$A3),COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,$A3),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: @ Harun24hr Thanks for your super fast reply, I tried the formula and am getting result in column B only not in column C. For your reference am sharing the link of the sheet. Further, is it possible to update the formula with arrayformula to avoid copy paste in all the cells? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nj8sNmOpIKFJFsX6MqZHXZK55-IvF9deUtCBAtsCNRg/edit#gid=1743149299

Comment: You have to drag the formula to right den down.